# Getting zeros for and or statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data

```
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from pandas_datareader import data

df=yf.download('BTC-USD',start='2017-01-01',end='2021-05-31',interval='1d')

#I calculated simple moving average as follow 
df['SlowSMA']=df['Close'].ewm(span=11).mean()
df['FastSMA']=df['Close'].ewm(span=5).mean()
df['Shares'] = [1 if df.loc[ei,'FastSMA']>df.loc[ei, 'SlowSMA'] else 0 for ei in df.index]
df['PrevShares']=df['Shares'].shift(1)
```

I want to create a column for transaction cost. Meaning whenever a shares changes from 1 to 0 or from 0 to one we incure cost. However, if shares remain 0 or one for long time we did not make a trade so no cost.

I did the following but it gave transaction cost always 0s.

```
cost=8
df['TranCost'] = [df.loc[ei,'Shares']*cost if df.loc[ei,'prevshares'] == 0 & df.loc[ei,'Shares'] ==1 or df.loc[ei,'prevshares'] == 1 & df.loc[ei,'Shares'] == 0 else 0 for ei in df.index]  

Thanks
```

Comment: maybe write it as normal `for`-loop and use `print()` to see what you have in variables, and what you get with `or` and next with `&`. You should also check the same with brackets like `(...) & (...)` And you should check if you have to use `and`, `or`  or `&`, `|`

Comment: it could be shorter: `df.loc[ei,'prevshares'] + df.loc[ei,'Shares'] == 1` And because `int(True)` gives `1` and `int(False)` gives `0` so you could even use `int( df.loc[ei,'prevshares'] + df.loc[ei,'Shares'] == 1 ) * df.loc[ei,'Shares']*cost`

Comment: ``` df['TranCost'] = [cost if df.loc[ei,'prevshares']+ df.loc[ei,'Shares'] ==1  else 0 for ei in df.index]``` Thanks I did it this way and it worked! how can I upvote your answer?

Comment: when you have low reputation (small points) then you have to wait few minutes to upvote answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can test it simpler using

```
df.loc[ei,'prevshares'] + df.loc[ei,'Shares'] == 1
```

You could also use `apply()` instead of `for ei in df.index`

```
cost = 8

def process(row):
    if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1:
        return cost
    else:
        return 0
    
df['TranCost'] = df.apply(process, axis=1)
```

or using `lambda`

```
df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: cost if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1 else 0, axis=1)
```

You could also use fact that `int(True)` gives `1` and `int(False)` gives `0`
and use it with `int( .... == 1)`

```
df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: cost * int(row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1), axis=1)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
#!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf

df=yf.download('BTC-USD', start='2017-01-01', end='2021-05-31', interval='1d')

# I calculated simple moving average as follow 
df['SlowSMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=11).mean()
df['FastSMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=5).mean()
#df['Shares'] = [1 if df.loc[ei,'FastSMA'] > df.loc[ei, 'SlowSMA'] else 0 for ei in df.index]
#df['Shares'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row['FastSMA'] > row['SlowSMA']), axis=1)
df['Shares'] = (df['FastSMA'] > df['SlowSMA']).astype(int)

df['PrevShares'] = df['Shares'].shift(1)

cost = 8

def process(row):
    if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1:
        return cost
    else:
        return 0
    
df['TranCost'] = df.apply(process, axis=1)
print(df[['PrevShares', 'Shares', 'TranCost']])

df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: cost if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1 else 0, axis=1)
print(df[['PrevShares', 'Shares', 'TranCost']])

df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: cost * int(row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1), axis=1)
print(df[['PrevShares', 'Shares', 'TranCost']])
```

---

**BTW:**

You can use fact that `int(True)` gives `1` and `int(False)` gives `0` to calculate `Shares`

with `apply()`

```
df['Shares'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row['FastSMA'] > row['SlowSMA']), axis=1)
```

without `apply()`

```
df['Shares'] = (df['FastSMA'] > df['SlowSMA']).astype(int)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Use `row['Cost']` instead of `df['Cost']` to get value `Cost` only from current row. If you use `df['Cost']` then you get all values from column and then you get many values in cell.

BTW: shorter `df['Cost'] = 0.005 * df['Close']`

```
df['Cost'] = 0.005 * df['Close']

df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Cost'] if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1 else 0, axis=1)
```

You may even do it in one step without creating column `Cost`

```
df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0.005*row['Close'] if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1 else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Furas. That was very helpful. I would like to ask you please if I changed cost as follow ``` df['Cost']=np.multiply(0.005,df["Close"])```  df['TranCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: df['Cost'] if row['PrevShares'] + row['Shares'] == 1 else 0, axis=1) it give me rows with dates do you know what is the reason or how to fix it?

Comment: use `row['Cost']` instead of `df['Cost']` to get value `Cost` only from current row. If you use `df['Cost']` then you get all values from column. BTW: shorter `df['Cost'] = 0.005 * df["Close"]`

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated Furas